# Customize pyrocms installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation, customization, pyrocms

I have a site built in Pyrocms

-It is a product, which would be installed on multiple domains.

my requirement is to make an installation out of it, where all the themes and modules developed be the same and i also want to add few extra options/steps fields to be entered while installation. Is it possible?and if yes then How?

I want to make sure all the developed/modified modules and db + theme and admin settings are handled during installation

Thanks allot in advance every one.

Comment: Do you want to customize the installer? then you have to modify the installer. thats all. Go to installer folder and make your changes.

Comment: Thanks @JahandidehAR, yes I modified the installer's view and added some extra required fields to it, but i still can't figure out
-how will i add extra db tables and the default pyrocms data in tables
so when the set up is completed, it should have my developed theme installed by default and settings data as i have working now, and also my developed modules installed and working

Comment: About modules and themes, one thing I am aware of is that when you include a module or theme files into the installation package, they will be installed automatiacally by installing the pyrocms.

Comment: yes @JahandidehAR exactly, but those modules are in system\cms\modules, what about modules in addons\shared_addons\modules, would they be installed automatically also?

Comment: I dug into the installer, I found an sql directory, which holds some of the basic default table structure, and also got an import db method in libraries, but the script is still ambiguous,it seems like a third party api is used may be while creating some tables

Comment: Actually I guess so. They will be installed too. Go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39995/discussion-between-jahandideh-ar-and-engr-waqas)